# Kafka Processor API with exactly once semantic for each record processed

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

> Scenario:
>
> ```
>  We are using kafka processor API ( not DSL ) for reading records from source topic, stream 
>  processor will write records to one or more target topics. 
>
>  We know exactly once can be implemented for the entire processor level by using : 
>  props.put("isolation.level", "read_committed"); 
>
>  But we want to decide based on the incoming records key if we want exactly once or at-least once semantic .
> ```

```
import org.apache.kafka.streams.processor.Processor;
public class StreamRouterProcessor implements Processor<String,Object> 
{
   private ProcessorContext context;

   @Override
   public void init(ProcessorContext context) {
   }


   @Override
   public void process(String eventName, String eventMessage) // this is called for each record
   {
   }
}
```

> Is there a way to select exactly-once or at-least once on the fly for
>   each record 
>       being processed ( perhaps for each record processed by the process() method above) ? .

Answer (score 1):

1. For enabling `exactly_once` semantic you should use `StreamsConfig.PROCESSING_GUARANTEE_CONFIG` property. `ConsumerConfig.ISOLATION_LEVEL_CONFIG` (`isolation.level`) is consumer config and should be use if you use *raw Consumer*
2. It is not possible to choose processing guarantees (`exactly-once` or `at-least-once`) at message level

Comment: Thank you sir for the answer.